# C++ linked list Segmentation fault and valgrind errors

Tags: c++, valgrind

i need to code a linked list for university in c++, mostly to practice coding iterators.
I tested it with some basic cases and it works but after i pass it in valgrind and the test server for the program i get a list of different errors. Maybe somebody can help me not to despair.
(At the end i will append the error list)

```
template <typename T = float>
class ForwardList
{
 
    struct Node
    {
        /// Constructs a Node from a data value and a link to the next element.
        Node(const T &data, Node *next) : data{data}, next{next} {}

        /// A Node owns all nodes after it, so it deletes them on destruction
        ~Node() { delete next; }

        
    //Performs a deep copy of the Node and all Nodes after it. Bad practice but we got it like that
        Node *clone() const
        {
            if (next == nullptr)
            {
                return new Node{data, nullptr};
            }
            else
            {
                return new Node{data, next->clone()};
            }
        }

        T data;
        Node *next;
    };

public:

    ForwardList() : head(nullptr) {}

    /// Copy constructor performs a deep copy of the other list's Nodes
    ForwardList(const ForwardList &other)
    {
        head = other.head->clone();
    }

    /// Destructor makes sure that all Nodes are correctly destroyed
    ~ForwardList()
    {
        while (head->next != nullptr)
        {
            Node *tmp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
        delete head;
    }

    /// Copy assignment operator uses the copy-and-swap idiom to make a safe
    /// assignment
    ForwardList &operator=(ForwardList other)
    {
        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }

   
    /// Add an element to the front of the list.
    void push_front(const T &value)
    {   
        std::cout << "Num: " << numberOfNodes << std::endl;

        Node *item = new Node(value, nullptr);
        if (head==nullptr)
        {
            head = item;
        }else
        {
            item->next=head;
            head = item;
        }
         numberOfNodes++;
    }

    /// Remove the first element of the list. Calling this function on an empty
    /// list is undefined behavior. When implementing this function, be careful
    /// to delete the one and only the one element that is removed.
    void pop_front()
    {
        Node *item;
        item = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = item;
        numberOfNodes--;
    }

    /// Get a reference to the first element of the list
    /// (const and non-const version)
    T &front()
    {
        return head->data;
    }
    const T &front() const
    {
        return head->data;
    }

    /// Return true is the list is empty
    bool empty() const
    {
        return numberOfNodes == 0 ? true : false;
    }
    std::size_t size() const
    {
        return numberOfNodes;
    }

    friend void swap(ForwardList &l, ForwardList &r)
    {
        Node *tmp = l.head;
        l.head = r.head;
        r.head = tmp;
    }

private:
    Node *head;
    size_t numberOfNodes = 0;
};
```

And now the fun part (i will put it on pastebin because its pretty long):
https://pastebin.com/4JAKkJtP

Comment: Note: The more we have to change in order to make your code compile and run the more likely we are to accidentally insert new bugs or fix bugs. In the former case you get wrong answers and in the latter case you get no answers. Either is undesirable for everyone involved.

Comment: Also note that where a program crashes is good information to have because it helps start the search, but a program can be mortally wounded by a bug and then stagger on for a long time afterward before finally falling over and dying in perfectly innocent code.

Comment: You will want to figure out what input causes the segfault, and you will want to find out exactly what line is core-dumping.

Comment: You can just copy the code and it should work, i just forgot the includes 
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

Comment: The segfault happens in the push_front function but i dont understand whats wrong with my implementation

Comment: Quick hack: the `push_front` function looks like it can be reduced to `head= new Node(value, head); numberOfNodes++;` because you wrote a good `Node` constructor. Great job!

Comment: that was my first approach but it caused the same segfault in main function, after inserting the second element

Comment: If you ever have an empty list, `while (head->next != nullptr)` in `~ForwardList()` is fatal. There is no `head` node to get a `next` from. I'd rewrite to `while (head)` and remove the `delete head;` at the end

Comment: Yeah makes sense. thanks, i changed it to: while (head){Node *tmp = head; head=head->next;delete tmp; }

Comment: That leads to the next problem: The nodes are deleting the next node. If the linked list is deleting nodes and the nodes are ALSO deleting nodes, you're going to have a bad time. One of then should do the job, not both. I recommend the linked list doing the job because if you have Nodes making recursive calls to their  destructor in a linked list you've got potential stack overflows with long lists.

Comment: Nothing wrong with `push_front` that I can see other than it can be much shorter. You tried the shorter approach and got fooled into thinking it didn't work because of a bug elsewhere, probably the double `delete`s.

Comment: Thanks i forgot that the Nodes are deleting the next node. I still have one problem with my iterator, i edit the paste. Thanks for the help. 
The segfault was caused by the double delete not my push front method. I really didnt thought this way

Comment: i figured it out im just stupid. i accidently wrote "!=" in the "bool operator==(const Iterator &other) const" function instead of "==" and forgot to correct it in my code, after i corrected it in the question above

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that `~Node` tries to delete its `next`, and you also try to walk the list in `~ForwardList`.  By deleting `~Node()`, you let `ForwardList` handle cleanup and everything works.

The clue here is that `valgrind` reported use after free, meaning something was deleting a pointer twice.  That was a clue to look at everything that deletes a `Node*` (or really, `delete` in general).

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot i just have one problem remaining, i edited the paste

Comment: @Marcel Don't move the goalposts. That's a new question.

Comment: @Marcel - Before you ask the new question, I'd suggest trying to user your debugger and figure out the problem on your own.  You'll learn a lot more going through that process, and since you're using `valgrind` that already puts you head and shoulders above most people who ask for debugging help.

Comment: Sorry i will change it back to original state afterwards